# Convert string to code in Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme

How do I convert a string into the corresponding code in PLT Scheme (which does not contain the `string->input-port` method)?  For example, I want to convert this string:

```
"(1 (0) 1 (0) 0)"
```

into this list:

```
'(1 (0) 1 (0) 0)
```

Is it possible to do this without opening a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scheme has procedure `read` for reading s-expressions from input port and you can convert a string to input stream with `string->input-port`. So, you can read a Scheme object from a string with

```
(read (string->input-port "(1 (0) 1 (0) 0)"))
```

I don't have Scheme installed, so I only read it [from reference](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/scheme/documentation/scheme.html) and didn't actually test it.

Comment: For anybody coming here using Guile Scheme: `(read (open-input-string "(quote foo)"))`.

Answer (score 5):

From PLT Scheme manual:

`(open-input-string string [name-v])` creates an input port that reads bytes from the UTF-8 encoding (see section 1.2.3) of string. The optional `name-v` argument is used as the name for the returned port; the default is `'string`.

Comment: This looks like abstraction inversion in Scheme.  Common Lisp has a `read-from-string` function.

Comment: Yes, it seems - read reads only from input ports, and opening input port for reading from file is in R5RS, but making input port for reading from string is not. So it is the source of question. Mit scheme has string->input-port, PLT - open-input-string.

Answer (score 2):

From this similar question on [comp.lang.scheme](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.scheme/browse_thread/thread/30494207342e4c71) you can save the string to a file then read from it.

That might go something like this example code:

```
(let ((my-port (open-output-file "Foo")))
  (display "(1 (0) 1 (0) 0)" my-port)
  (close-output-port my-port))

(let* ((my-port (open-input-file "Foo"))
       (answer (read my-port)))
  (close-input-port my-port)
  answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Many schemes have `with-input-from-string str thunk` that executes `thunk` in a context where `str` is the standard input port. For example in gambit scheme:

`(with-input-from-string "(foo bar)"
  (lambda () (read)))`

evaluates to:

`(foo bar)`

The lambda is necessary because a `thunk` should be a procedure taking no arguments.

Comment: And since `read` is a procedure taking no arguments you could shorthen the above example to `(with-input-from-string "(foo bar)" read)` .