# How to eval strings in racket

Tags: string, eval, racket

I'm trying to understand how to get the eval function to read a string and evaluate the content that's inside the string.

Currently I know that

```
> (eval '(+ 1 2))
   3
```

but I'm not that knowledgeable with the use of racket. So at the moment I'm trying to get it so that I can do this:

```
> (eval "(+ 1 2)")
   3
```

Any advice or links to useful resources would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/q/318952/535275

Comment: Also, most idiomatic Racket code avoids use of eval. Maybe you have an example where you really need it, but you might want to read [this article](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html) about the use of eval in Racket.

Answer (score 22):

You want to use `read` together with `open-input-string`.  Like so:

```
-> (eval (read (open-input-string "(+ 1 2)")))
3
```

You can also use `with-input-from-string`:

```
-> (with-input-from-string "(+ 1 2)"
     (lambda () (eval (read))))
3
```

Comment: I prefer to use `(eval (call-with-input-string "(+ 1 2)" read))`. Why? 1. String port is automatically closed before the `eval` (unlike the `open-input-string` solution; okay, so for string ports, it probably doesn't matter too much (unless you're using Guile ;-)), but still); 2. It doesn't use fluids/parameters (unlike the `with-input-from-string` solution).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Are there situations in which one would want to use this to alter code instead of a macro?  I can think of a few, but I don't know macros well enough to say for certain

Comment: @frank Personally I would use macros for all such situations that I can think of, but feel free to post examples that you feel are better served by `eval` and I'll let you know. :-D

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I am writing code to generate triangle-mesh skin from a voxel representation of a human form, and the only difference between 2 sections of code is "top" vs. "bottom" in some variable names.  I can post it somewhere later, but the entire source code is probably too long for SO.  I can always post the most relevant section, however.  I imagine if I tag it as "Racket" you'll be fairly likely to see it; I've seen you all over the Racket questions on this site.  Thanks for all your contributions!

Comment: @frank You can always put your code in a Gist, then link to it here. And, always my pleasure; I'm glad to be of help. :-)