# String containing a list into an actual list

Tags: scheme, racket

I was just wondering if there's a way to make:
"`((a b))`" into `'((a b))`.

I used 
`(symbol->string "((a b))")` which gives me `'|((a b))|`

And that's not exactly what I need. 
I need a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do this in Racket:

```
(call-with-input-string "((a b))" read)
=> '((a b))
```

The advantage of using `call-with-input-string` is that the string port is automatically closed, as has been mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10399415/201359).

Comment: Why use `eval` at all? Just use `(call-with-input-string "((a b))" read)`.

Comment: That works too, also (read (open-input-string "((a b))")) gives '((a b)). Now, what takes more memory? I don't really mind that issue now but I was just wondering, thank you for your support! :)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young right you are. I was thinking of the general case of evaluating a expression in a string, but for a symbol list `call-with-input-string` is enough

Comment: @DavidMerinos they should be about the same - don't worry about it, the nice thing about this solution is that the port gets automatically closed, preventing leaks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `read` and `open-input-string` together to parse strings into lists.

```
> (define (string->list str) (read (open-input-string str)))
> (string->list "((a b))")
'((a b))
```

This converts the string first into an `input-port` (a data stream) and then from an `input-port` into a `list`. See the documentation for [open-input-string](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stringport.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._open-input-string%29%29) and [read](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29).